# Python Seaborn Plot ValueError

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have a pandas dataframe `df` and am trying to use the seaborn library to create a violin plot.

```
    rank  sentiment category
0     1   0.657413        m
1     2   0.895769        m
2     3  -0.435457        m
3     4  -0.717959        m
4     5   0.869688        m
```

This is the seaborn line:

```
sns.violinplot(x="rank", y="senitment", hue="category", data=df)
```

I keep getting this `ValueError`

```
ValueError: Could not interpret input 'senitment'
```

Full traceback

/Users/jrs/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/seaborn/categorical.py in violinplot(x, y, hue, data, order, hue_order, bw, cut, scale, scale_hue, gridsize, width, inner, split, orient, linewidth, color, palette, saturation, ax, **kwargs)
       2299                              bw, cut, scale, scale_hue, gridsize,
       2300                              width, inner, split, orient, linewidth,
    -> 2301                              color, palette, saturation)
       2302 
       2303     if ax is None:

```
/Users/jrs/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/seaborn/categorical.py in __init__(self, x, y, hue, data, order, hue_order, bw, cut, scale, scale_hue, gridsize, width, inner, split, orient, linewidth, color, palette, saturation)
    535                  color, palette, saturation):
    536 
--> 537         self.establish_variables(x, y, hue, data, orient, order, hue_order)
    538         self.establish_colors(color, palette, saturation)
    539         self.estimate_densities(bw, cut, scale, scale_hue, gridsize)

/Users/jrs/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/seaborn/categorical.py in establish_variables(self, x, y, hue, data, orient, order, hue_order, units)
    145                 if isinstance(input, string_types):
    146                     err = "Could not interpret input '{}'".format(input)
--> 147                     raise ValueError(err)
    148 
    149             # Figure out the plotting orientation

ValueError: Could not interpret input 'senitment'
```

I've tried using .reset_index() on the df and changing data types, but no luck. Thoughts?

Comment: typo in 'sentiment' in your sns.violinplot line

Comment: Dear lord.  Thank you.  Nap time.

Comment: We all need an extra pair of eyes sometimes... However, on SO you have thousands of eyes. :)  Night-night.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sns.violinplot(x="rank", y="sentiment", hue="category", data=df)
```